# Remove sliding effect on sencha touch tabs

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am using tabs for navigating to different views.The views are in `'xype' container`.
I am using function like this to load different views

```
    Ext.getCmp('contactcontainer').setActiveItem(2);
```

But I need to remove the sliding effect while new view is called. 
How can it be done?
I am using sencha touch 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just simply specify the animation config as "False". That will do.

Like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    config: {
        layout: {
            animation: false,
            type: 'card'
        },
```

If you are using Sencha Architect, you can just select the tab panel
   --> Go to Config panel --> select animation field --> set 'False'